# Putting an std::string into a char[][] array

Tags: c++, string, file-io, multidimensional-array

So I'm attempting to create a Befunge interperter and reading a text file into an array.
I'm using this code:

```
char map[100][100]; //not 85 x 20
//load the source
ifstream f;
f.open("file.txt", ios::in);
string s;
int i = 0;
while(f.good() && i < 100)
{
    getline(f, s);
    map[i] = s.c_str();
    i++;
}
```

This doesn't work, does anyone know a way to do it without manually looping through the string?

Comment: But do you understand _why_ it doesn't work? That's rather important...

Comment: Use `strcpy` and watch out for buffer overflow. You cannot assign to an array. Or even better, use `std::vector<std::string>` rather than yacky C strings

Comment: Any reason you can't use `std::vector<std::string>` or even `std::string[100]`? If you're using C++, take advantage of its types!

Comment: A vector is probably the best idea since I'm planning for unbounded storage, and yes @ildjarn I know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strncpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncpy.html) and specify the number of bytes:

```
strncpy(map[i], s.c_str(), 100);
map[i][99] = '\0'; /* this could trim s.c_str(), but at least you don't get an overflow */
```

instead of:

```
map[i] = s.c_str();
```

By specifying the number of bytes copied as, at most, `100`, you ensure that you don't overflow `map[i]`. The `strncpy()` function will pad `map[i]` with terminators, if `strlen(s.c_str()) < 100`. In the case where `strlen(s.c_str()) >= 100`, the string will be truncated in order to provide `map[i]` with the requisite null terminator.

Comment: This would work but I'm going to use a std::vector<std::string> since I need no limits on storage. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Using a `vector` of `string` would definitely be the most idiomatic C++ approach, and you wouldn't have to deal with line length issues (at least up to system memory, more or less).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is safer to do so

```
char* map[100];
....   

while(f.good() && i < 100)
{
    getline(f, s);
    map[i] = new char[s.length() + 1];
    strcpy (map[i], s.c_str());
    i++;
}
```

Comment: To be really safe, you might want to test the result of `map[i] = ...` to ensure that you actually have that space available, before the `strcpy()`.

Comment: I said "safer", not "the safest" ))))  I gave an idea and direction for thought, not a ready piece of code

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to the other answers already posted in here, you should NOT be attempting to use strcpy to copy into "map".
Before you do any copying, you want to ensure that you do not overrun the buffer. To do this, you should not use the size of the source, but instead the size of the destination. The reason for this is that the source could potentially be longer than the destination has room. In order to avoid an issue that might not rear its head until you've done some other
intensive computations you should ensure that you don't attempt to copy into a destination that isn't large enough to contain what you are trying to copy into it.

This is the function signature for copying strings (well, the one you should be using here):

```
strncpy(dest, source, size);
```

Here's what you should use instead:

```
strncpy(map[i], s.c_str(), sizeof(map[i]));
```

Edit:

Alternatively you could use strncpy_s() (if you are on Windows!), which allows you to specify both source and destination lengths.

```
strncpy_s(dest, dest_size, source, source_size)
```